# Build a highchart graph using excel file as input

Tags: javascript, excel, highcharts

I want to build a small prototype where i read data from excel, which will have many columns, and select only 2 columns i.e 'status' and 'value'. Convert the same to high-chart data.
I want to develop this using java script. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am trying to read excel file, the problem is there are many columns in my excel sheet, and i wan only few to display in the chart. So getting those is what i am facing issue

Comment: Ok, but without anything to work with I don't know where you are having issues, what have you tried so far?

Comment: export data to csv and use Highcharts data module if you do not want to manually parse data. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module